# Remove attribute multiple from chosen

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I have two select: `method` and `list`, when method value is 1,list have multiple choice but when method value is 2, don't have multiple choices,

this is de code:

```
$method.chosen().change(function()
{
    if($method.val() == '1')
    {
        $list.attr('multiple');
    }
    else
    {
        $list.removeAttr('multiple');
    }
$list.trigger("liszt:updated");
});
```

And didn't work the remove attribute multiple, when i don't use chosen plugins works,
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was create two select and use show and hide jquery method:

```
$method.chosen().change(function()
{
if($method.val() == '1')
{
    $list.show();
    $list2.hide();
}
else
{
    $list.hide();
    $list2.show();
}
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `$list.attr('multiple');` will return the value of the attribute `multiple`.

What you want is to set a value, so try :

```
$list.attr('multiple', true);
```

Comment: OK, but the problem is with removeAttr('multiple'), with the plugin chosen not work, thanks!.

Comment: Are you entering in the `else` condition?

Answer (score 0):

using `Prop` will work
Try This :

```
$list.Prop('multiple',false);
```

Comment: Not work, i think when a chosen is show,can't change the type

Comment: The attr are removed but, the Select Chosen not change, the problem is Chosen Plugin, Thanks a lot

Comment: Finally... I use two select with show and hide method, Thanks :)

Comment: Please post your answer..so that i will also know how to do it